# Database data update failure

Tags: database, visual-studio-2013

My program can't update it's data. The code has been checked by my lecturer. When i clicked on the update button, the data didn't change. There's no conflict with the code. The program just didn't respond to the update query.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmUpdate

Dim con1 As New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= MainSource.accdb")

Private Sub btnUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUp.Click

    If txtID.Text = "" Or txtItem.Text = "" Or ComboBox1.Text = "" Or txtPrice.Text = "" Or txtStock.Text = "" Or TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then

        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields..", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Else

        Dim sqlupdate As String
        sqlupdate = "UPDATE Inventory SET Item_Name=@Item_Name, Category=@Category, Stock_Quantity=@Stock_Quantity, Item_Price=@Item_Price, Supplier_ID=@Supplier_ID, Supplier_Name=@Supplier_Name WHERE Item_ID=@Item_ID"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlupdate, con1)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Item_ID", txtID.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Item_Name", txtItem.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Category", ComboBox1.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Stock_Quantity", txtStock.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Item_Price", txtPrice.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Supplier_ID", TextBox1.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Supplier_Name", TextBox2.Text))
        con1.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con1.Close()
        ClearTextBox(Me)
        Me.Close()
        RefreshDGV()

    End If

End Sub
```

If you see anything wrong with it, do say. I just want to get to the bottom of the problem. The database is placed in the debug folder named as **MainSource**.

Thanks

Edit: I'm using DataGridView to display the content of the database. One DataGridView for one table. I have 4 tables in the database. Each table has a separate DataGridView for itself.

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim sql As String
        sql = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY"
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con1)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("INVENTORY")
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Dim sql1 As String
        sql1 = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY"
        Dim adapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, con1)
        Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(sql1, con1)
        Dim dt1 As New DataTable("INVENTORY")

```
    Dim sql2 As String
    sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Supplier"
    Dim adapter2 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql2, con1)
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable("Supplier")
    adapter2.Fill(dt2)
    DataGridView9.DataSource = dt2
    Dim sql3 As String
    sql3 = "SELECT * FROM Supplier"
    Dim adapter3 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql3, con1)
    Dim cmd3 As New OleDbCommand(sql3, con1)
    Dim dt3 As New DataTable("Supplier")

    con1.Open()
    Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader
    myreader.Read()

    Dim myreader2 As OleDbDataReader = cmd3.ExecuteReader
    myreader2.Read()
    con1.Close()

    Dim sql4 As String
    sql4 = "SELECT * FROM Purchase"
    Dim adapter4 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql4, con1)
    Dim dt4 As New DataTable("Purchase")
    adapter4.Fill(dt4)
    DataGridView2.DataSource = dt4
    Dim sql5 As String
    sql5 = "SELECT * FROM Purchase"
    Dim adapter5 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql5, con1)
    Dim cmd5 As New OleDbCommand(sql5, con1)
    Dim dt5 As New DataTable("Purchase")

    Dim sql6 As String
    sql6 = "SELECT * FROM Restock"
    Dim adapter6 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql6, con1)
    Dim dt6 As New DataTable("Restock")
    adapter6.Fill(dt6)
    DataGridView6.DataSource = dt6
    Dim sql7 As String
    sql7 = "SELECT * FROM Restock"
    Dim adapter7 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql7, con1)
    Dim cmd7 As New OleDbCommand(sql7, con1)
    Dim dt7 As New DataTable("Restock")

    con1.Open()
    Dim myreader6 As OleDbDataReader = cmd7.ExecuteReader
    myreader6.Read()
    Dim myreader5 As OleDbDataReader = cmd5.ExecuteReader
    myreader5.Read()
    con1.Close()

    Dim sql14 As String
    sql14 = "SELECT * FROM Supplier"
    Dim adapter14 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql14, con1)
    Dim dt14 As New DataTable("Supplier")
    adapter14.Fill(dt14)
    DataGridView9.DataSource = dt14
    Dim sql15 As String
    sql15 = "SELECT * FROM Supplier"
    Dim adapter15 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql15, con1)
    Dim cmd15 As New OleDbCommand(sql15, con1)
    Dim dt15 As New DataTable("Supplier")

    Dim myreader8 As OleDbDataReader = cmd15.ExecuteReader
    myreader8.Read()
    con1.Close()

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

This is from the main window. Hope it helps.

Comment: "The program just didn't respond to the update query." -- What does that mean?  Is there an error?  If so, what's the error message?

Comment: The window for the update section just closes as expected. I had set the window to automatically close after clicking the update button. But after the closing, the old data remains in the display. The new updated data didn't. The update failed. No error message was displayed.

Comment: have you tried to query the results after the update with a select * from Inventory to see what you get?

Comment: I don't know about that. Can you explain the process, please?

Comment: You are calling con1.Open after assigning it to the cmd object.  Does that matter?

Comment: @OldProgrammer should it be anyway different?

Comment: @user3479671 forgot to mention

Comment: @roryap forgot to mention